# Pandas pivot table on three columns, while having the third column showing average numbers of the original colum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table with the first 2 columns pivoted as rows as in Excel Pivot, while the third column showing average numbers as in Values field in Excel Pivot table. I have tried the code below ...I have got the values I want but in not in the desired format.

The code:

```py
pd.pivot_table(merged_df, values='Tumor Volume (mm3)',index=['Drug'], columns='Timepoint',aggfunc='mean').T
```

Result:

[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43dxH.png)

While the desired output should be something like that:
[desired output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yeix.png)

Merged DataFrame:

[Merged Data Frame: merged_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT5KQ.png)

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe, we can't work with an image

Comment: How do the original dataframe look like?

Answer (score 0):

As I have limited information and know nothing about your original dataframe.

You can try the following solution and let me know, if it works.

```py
#added `Timepoint` as an index.
#removed transpose from the end

pd.pivot_table(merged_df, values='Tumor Volume (mm3)',index=['Drug','Timepoint'], columns='Timepoint',aggfunc='mean')
```

## Edit 1

After checking the merged DF, you problem could be solved by using `groupby` function, as shown below.

```py
temp_df = merged_df[['Drug','Timepoint','Tumor Volume (mm3)']]

tdf = temp_df.groupby(['Drug','Timepoint']).['Tumor Volume (mm3)'].mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi....Thanks for your answer....The original dataframe derived from 2 separate dataframes, the first had 2 columns [Mouse ID  and Drug] and the second dataframe columns [Mouse ID,Timepoint , Tumor Volume (mm3),
Metastatic Sites]

The goal is to create a pivot table like showed in the linked image in the initial post. 

The code you provided broke ….didn't work.....Thanks!

Comment: what about the merged df, add that in the answer.

Comment: DataFrame Screenshot added to original post....please check now

Comment: The first part only worked (the Group by part), all together didn't work